# Current time when MySQL record is saved to database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm working with Zend Framework 1.12 and Mysql. I want to add column in database, which save currenct datetime when record was inserted into table.

Anyone knows how can I defined this column?
This function must working on Mysql site, not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must change column type to TIMESTAMP , and in default field set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

You can just define the column like:

```
DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do so.

You can define data type `TIMESTAMP` and set default value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

You can define column with data type `datetime` and use `now()` or `sysdate()` to get current date and time.

For eg.

```
 INSERT INTO `table_name`(current_time) VALUES(now());
```

**or**

```
 INSERT INTO `table_name`(current_time) VALUES(sysdate());
```